# Ajax serialise - issue with data format

Tags: ajax, post, format

I have several inputs formatted with this jquery plugin [here.](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

I use $.ajax to do my mysql insert:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'xxxx.php',
   data: $('#new_form').serialize(),
}),
```

I face an issue as my input values are formatted with the plugins and can't get into mysql db.
As an example:
Input value: $450,000.00 is not accepted.

Is there a way to unformat within the serialise function values that have a specific classes (like class="money")?

Thanks for your help!

---

I have tried the below code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'xxx.php',
data: $('#new_form').serialize(),
dataType:"json",
beforeSend: function(){
    $(".money").cleanVal();
    },

<script>
      function cleanVal(v) {        
        return v.replace(/^\,/,'');
};
</script>
```

the result of the insert in mysql is still 450 for 450,000.
Do you have an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make it work with beforehand. I found a solution which is to unmask values before calling ajax.

If anyone knows why it does not work with beforesend, thanks for letting me know.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the plugin `$.cleanVal()` method to retrieve the unmasked type value of the corresponding HTML element, prior to your AJAX form submission. So something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'xxxx.php',
  data: $('#new_form').serialize(),
  beforeSend: function(){
    $(".money").cleanVal();
  }
}),
```

Comment: thanks, i have edited my question with your suggestion above. it does not work. any idea? thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error message in your browser debugger console?

Comment: No, everything is executed without any error. However, the outcome is still incorrect.

Comment: @Harold You don't need to define the `cleanVal()` function. It's part of the jquery mask plugin. (Go to their doc, and search for `cleanVal`).

Comment: thanks i understand why i struggle. It is not about cleanval() - the function alone works great. The problem is that beforeSend does not seems to actually to change the actual value (here: $450,000) that will be picked up by serialize. it is weird but it seems that the data were already collected before executing beforeSend. Have you ever tried your solution? thanks again